# How to correctly get the error of a timeseries mean, when each point in the timeseries has errors?

Tags: time-series, unevenly-spaced-time-series, types-of-averages

I have time-series data (brGDGT samples from a core with an age-depth model), and each data point in the time-series has an error associated with it as per the dummy table below.

| time | value | plus | minus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15.9 | 10 | 2 | 1 |
| 12.8 | 12 | 2.5 | 2 |
| 11.0 | 9 | 1.5 | 1 |
| 9.3 | 16 | 4. | 3.5 |

I want to be able to report the mean value and combined error of a certain time period, e.g. 16-11 Ma = 10.3 +x/-y, but I am unsure what the correct way to combine errors is.  Is there a method I should apply? I am not sure if this is time-series specific, or if it would use the same method if it were just a pool of measurements.

Comment: How are these $\pm$ values defined/calculated? We should know how they relate to the statistical population in order to understand what can be meaningfully done with them.

Comment: I have multiple data types with time-series data, none of which are my area of research. This is part of a data compilation project. 
For the GDGT example, the +/- values are a combination of analytical error and the RMSE of of the modern calibration curve. So using it as my example was a poor one as the error would be fixed.
For d18O the error is 1std, so presumably based on multiple measurements of the same sample.

Comment: Other ways people have done this is to report the mean value, the max and min over the time series, or the mean value and the value 1 std above and below. Now I am wondering if it should be mean and 1std from the values, with an extra column for fixed known error such as the analytical and calibration error in GDGTs, but I am not sure if I should or how to incorporate the existing std per sample as per the case of d18O.